# How to disable BottomNavigationView shift mode when "re-adding" TabbedPage children in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have an XF application using `BottomNavigationView` in `Android` side that removes and add `TabbedPage` children depending on the user mode. Below is my `Android` renderer:

```
public class BottomTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{

    public BottomTabPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (ViewGroup != null && ViewGroup.ChildCount > 0)
        {
            BottomNavigationMenuView bottomNavigationMenuView = FindChildOfType<BottomNavigationMenuView>(ViewGroup);

            if (bottomNavigationMenuView != null)
            {
                var shiftMode = bottomNavigationMenuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");

                shiftMode.Accessible = true;
                shiftMode.SetBoolean(bottomNavigationMenuView, false);
                shiftMode.Accessible = false;
                shiftMode.Dispose();

                for (var i = 0; i < bottomNavigationMenuView.ChildCount; i++)
                {
                    var item = bottomNavigationMenuView.GetChildAt(i) as BottomNavigationItemView;
                    if (item == null) continue;

                    item.SetShiftingMode(false);
                    item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);
                }

                if (bottomNavigationMenuView.ChildCount > 0) bottomNavigationMenuView.UpdateMenuView();
            }

        }

        T FindChildOfType<T>(ViewGroup viewGroup) where T : Android.Views.View
        {
            if (viewGroup == null || viewGroup.ChildCount == 0) return null;

            for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null) return typedChild;

                if (!(child is ViewGroup)) continue;

                var result = FindChildOfType<T>(child as ViewGroup);

                if (result != null) return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
   }
}
```

When the user starts the game by clicking a button, 4 out of 5 tabs at the bottom are removed. And when the user ends the game again by clicking a button the tabs are added again. I tried `xxx.Children.Insert()` to put the tabs back to their original position but this gives me the following errors:

```
Java.Lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
```

So I ended up with the following code:

```
public static void ReAddChildren()
{
   mainPage.Children.Remove(gameTabPage);
   mainPage.Children.Add(homeTabPage);
   mainPage.Children.Add(helpTabPage);
   mainPage.Children.Add(settingsTabPage);
   mainPage.Children.Add(dictTabPage);
   mainPage.Children.Add(gameTabPage);
 }
```

This works but now the `shiftingMode` is back. Anyone knows how I can disable this whenever I "re-add" the tab items?

Comment: If you want to disable the shifting mode, you could refer to the following link.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101465/how-to-disable-shifting-mode-on-bottomnavigationview

Comment: @L.Leon My renderer already disables the shifting mode. Its only when I remove and add the items again that the shifting mode is enabled again.

Answer (score 0):

Android just update it on 28.0.0 support library.
Not sure if Xamarin could access to this native method setLabelVisibilityMode() to disable the shifting or not.

```
navBottom.setLabelVisibilityMode(LabelVisibilityMode.LABEL_VISIBILITY_LABELED);
```

Answer (score 0):

In renderer you can easily use this extension method from Xamarin.Forms to manage shift mode.

https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/BottomNavigationViewUtils.cs

so you would get:

```
using static Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.BottomNavigationViewUtils;
public class BottomTabPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{

    public BottomTabPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (ViewGroup != null && ViewGroup.ChildCount > 0)
        {
            BottomNavigationMenuView bottomNavigationMenuView = FindChildOfType<BottomNavigationMenuView>(ViewGroup);

            if (bottomNavigationMenuView != null)
            {
                // use extension method from XF
                bottomNavigationMenuView.SetShiftMode(false, false);
            }

        }

        T FindChildOfType<T>(ViewGroup viewGroup) where T : Android.Views.View
        {
            if (viewGroup == null || viewGroup.ChildCount == 0) return null;

            for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
            {
                var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

                var typedChild = child as T;
                if (typedChild != null) return typedChild;

                if (!(child is ViewGroup)) continue;

                var result = FindChildOfType<T>(child as ViewGroup);

                if (result != null) return result;
            }

            return null;
        }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned from Pawel, you can easily use the extension method from Xamarin.Forms to manage shift mode. But this one was that worked for me

```
 public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{

    public CustomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (ViewGroup != null && ViewGroup.ChildCount > 0)
        {
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = FindChildOfType<BottomNavigationView>(ViewGroup);

            if (bottomNavigationView != null)
            {
                // use extension method from XF
                bottomNavigationView.SetShiftMode(false, false);
            }

        }
    }

    private T FindChildOfType<T>(ViewGroup viewGroup) where T : Android.Views.View
    {
        if (viewGroup == null || viewGroup.ChildCount == 0) return null;

        for (var i = 0; i < viewGroup.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = viewGroup.GetChildAt(i);

            var typedChild = child as T;
            if (typedChild != null) return typedChild;

            if (!(child is ViewGroup)) continue;

            var result = FindChildOfType<T>(child as ViewGroup);

            if (result != null) return result;
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected override void DispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        base.DispatchDraw(canvas);
    }


}
```